# Ember js for array binding

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on an application, where I am getting all categories through external api.

So now I need to get all subcategories for each category.

I have controller for that

```
   CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

   #return all categories hits an api/categories
   categories: (->

     App.Category.find()

   ).property()
```

So now I need to get all subcategories for each category.

Basically we get subcategories from external api for each category.

so structure is

```
  {"subcategories": [id: "1", name:"ss".. }
```

For this I have created another method to get subcategory for each category.

```
  subcategories: ( ->

    @get('categories').forEach (category) =>

     ##Get subcategories from external api

     subcategories = App.Subcategory.find(category.id)

     ##making an array of objects

     result = Ember.A()

     result.pushObject({ 

        category: categorys

       subcategories: subcategories
     )}

  ).property('@categories','@each')
```

so when I check subcategories it's always blank. What's wrong in it?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, since I'm not confortable with CoffeeScript, but it seems that you subgategories function does not return any result. I know return statements are optional in CS, but here I think you have to declare the result outside the forEach, and then return it at the end.

Comment: Hi thanks for comment.I have corrected question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058681/ember-js-get-items-in-loop